# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of undefined - Code working in FF but not Chrome or Safari

Tags: javascript

Okay, I know that this has been answered before, but as I'm new to JS, I need to ask again. I've created a gallery with a large slider image and thumbnails. When the thumbnail is clicked, it expands to show a larger image, and the slider image is swapped. It works beautifully in Firefox, but of course, does not work in Chrome or Safari. Here's the code:

```
var src = document.getElementById('slide').src;

function swap() {
    window.document.pic.src='../image path';
    }

function swap1() {
    window.document.pic.src='../image path';
    }   

function swap2() {
    window.document.pic.src='../image path';
    }

function swap3() {
    window.document.pic.src='../image path';
    }

function swap4() {
    window.document.pic.src='../image path';
    }

function swap5() {
    window.document.pic.src='../image path';
    }
```

```
<div class="gallery" align="center">

    <a href="../image path" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)">
        <img src="../image path" alt="Highslide JS"
        title="Click to enlarge" height="175" width="120" onclick="swap5()" id="slide" /></a>

    <a href="../image path" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)">
        <img src="../image path" alt="Highslide JS"
        title="Click to enlarge" height="175" width="120" onclick="swap()" id="slide" /></a>

    <a href="../image path" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)">
        <img src="../image path" alt="Highslide JS"
        title="Click to enlarge" height="175" width="120" onclick="swap1()" id="slide" /></a>

    <a href="../image path" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)">
        <img src="../image path" alt="Highslide JS"
        title="Click to enlarge" height="175" width="120" onclick="swap2()" id="slide" /></a>

    <a href="../image path" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)">
        <img src="../image path" alt="Highslide JS"
        title="Click to enlarge" height="175" width="120" onclick="swap3()" id="slide" /></a>

    <a href="../image path" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)">
        <img src="../image path" alt="Highslide JS"
        title="Click to enlarge" height="175" width="120" onclick="swap4()" id="slide" /></a>

</div>
```

I've replaced the actual path to the image and filename with "image path" just for the sake of anonymity. This is driving me nuts - any thoughts?

Comment: you have multiple ids 'slide', id should be unique.

Comment: also you dont seems do you jQuery but you add the tag ?

Comment: if you use jquery, its much easier, see my edit

Answer (score 0):

You could use data attributes to store the url of the img to swap:

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)">
     <img src="../image path" alt="Highslide JS"
        title="Click to enlarge" height="175" width="120" onclick="swap(this)" data-swapurl="url_swap_img.jpg"  />
</a>
```

JS:

```
function swap(img) {
   img.src = img.dataset.swapurl;
}
```

and you will need only one swap function.

Comment: Actually, I'm using three images, not two - one is the slider image, one is the thumbnail, and there is one other - when you click on the thumbnail, it expands to reveal the larger image and swaps the slider image at the same time.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle using this code: http://jsfiddle.net/F8Yfg/25/

When I click on the thumbnail, I want it to expand AND swap - when I click on the red thumbnail, it should swap to the red slider, etc.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that your variable `var src = document.getElementById('slide').src;` will return allways one value only, from the first element with `id="slide"`.

Make the id's unique!

responding to the new comment:

change the id's to 'swap1', 'swap2', etc or even better to the image name
then call just one function only and pass the image name to that function: like below

```
$('img').on('click', function(){
    my_link=$(this).attr('onclick');
    swap(my_link)
});

function swap(my_link){
    window.document.pic.src='../image path/'+my_link+'.jpg';
}
```

Comment: Okay, I should have seen that. Can I code it like this? 
var src = document.getElementById('slide, slide1, slide2, slide3, slide4, slide5').src;

Comment: I need to post more code tomorrow to show exactly what I'm doing - some of it did not show up in my original post. TBC.

Comment: I'd suggest you put the whole thing together in jsfiddle.net, this will help us to see into your issue easier

Comment: So here is what is supposed to happen: 

<div class="header">
  <a href="#"><img src="../img/gallery/image-largest.jpg" alt="blah" title="blah" id="pic" /></a>
</div>

<div class="gallery" align="center">

    <a href="../img/gallery/image-larger.jpg" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)">
        <img src="../img/gallery/image-thumb.jpg" alt="Highslide JS"
        title="Click to enlarge" height="175" width="120" onclick="swap5()" id="slide" /></a>
</div>

Since there are six images in the gallery, the above code would be repeated 5 more times (as in my original post).

Comment: I'd like to help you, put you have to put the whole thing together at jsfiddle, including some example images. And you didn't mention the use of Highslide.js for example

Comment: Yes, I did use Highslide and tweaked it a little. I don't know how to get the images up there. The thumbnail images I'm using are the same size as on the fiddle; the slider image is larger.

Comment: How do I get the example images up there?

Comment: provide absolute links instead of relatives, like: <img src="http ://www.yoursite.com/image path/img.jpg">

Comment: Okay. I didn't want to use the original images or use my test server, but maybe I can figure out where else to put them.

Comment: Okay, here's the fiddle with images - now the expander does not work, nor the swap. The expander usually does not work if it can't find the expander image, but I thought the path was correct. What's supposed to happen is that when you click on a thumbnail, it expands to reveal a larger image and the header image swaps out. Hope this gives you a better idea of what's going on. Again, it works perfectly in FF but not Chrome or Safari. http://jsfiddle.net/F8Yfg/6/

Comment: see my update fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hbrunar/F8Yfg/8/: it seems to work, at least it doesn't through any errors in the js console. What did you do wrong in your fiddle: You forgot to add Jquery in your fiddle (check if you have set up jquery in your code correctly) and you forgot to add the highslide.js script.

Comment: Sorry - I've never used jsfiddle before. The issue was not with the expander - that worked fine in FF, Chrome and Safari. The thing that did not work in Chrome and Safari was the swap. Clicking on the thumbnail is supposed to expand and swap the main slider.

Comment: check http://jsfiddle.net/hbrunar/F8Yfg/10/ I suppose that's what you want? Anyway as I said before: the id's should be unique, insyead of calling 5 or more functions doing basically the same use the approach I pointed out in the original answer. Also use your browser's console to check on javascript errors. hope that was useful for you

Comment: In the above fiddle the slider is not swapping. I did check the browser's console for errors - the error is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of undefined". I'm back to square one.

Comment: I'll try what you suggested above. Thanks.

Comment: I still don't understand how to make the slider swap with this code:

$('img').on('click', function(){
    my_link=$(this).attr('onclick');
    swap(my_link)
});

function swap(my_link){
    window.document.pic.src='../image path/'+my_link+'.jpg';
}


I want the large slider image to be replaced with another on click: for example, slider with slider1. The other part of this works fine, I just can't get it to swap. I'm very new to JS, so it's a little confusing.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle - when I click on the red thumbnail, I want it to expand AND swap to the red slider. Same with all of the other thumbnails.  http://jsfiddle.net/F8Yfg/25/